# .htaccess clean URLs with slugs 404 not found

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I apologize for asking this question once again, but I'm unable to make my URLs work without getting an 404 page error.

```
public_html
   .htaccess

   webroot+
      index.php
      article.php
```

I'm using htaccess to make the webroot folder the main document root ( I do not have access to virtual hosts)

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^site.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.site.com/$1 [R=301,L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !webroot/
RewriteRule (.*) /webroot/$1 [L]
```

I'm not sure if the issue is caused due to the code above but when I try making my URLs clean for seo I get an 404 page.

I'm trying to change `www.site.com/article.php?article_uid=number&article_title=title` **--->** `www.site.com/article/id/title/`

With the following code it allows the page to change the url but it gives me an 404 not found.

```
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \ /article\.php\?article_uid=([^&]+)&article_title=([^&\ ]+)
RewriteRule ^ /article/%1/%2/? [L,R=301,NE]

RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^article/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/?$ /article.php?article_uid=$1&article_title=$2 [L,QSA]
```

ex.

**The requested URL /webroot/article/id/title/ was not found on this server.**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change last rule to:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule (?:^|/)article/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/?$ webroot/article.php?article_uid=$1&article_title=$2 [L,QSA]
```

Comment: Me too, spend three hours after got some tips trying to fix it, here come's the expert .. 5 seconds later.. BOOM resolved xD thanks again, एक अच्छा दिन है.

Comment: Thanks, seeing hindi text really cheered me up :)

Comment: with the above code, how can i replace spaces with hyphens, such as articles/id/title-goes-here-and-has-hyphens instead of articles/id/title goes here and has no hyphens. Not sure where i should add something like [A-Za-z] in the code.

Comment: I cannot edit the above question, but I'd like to for the url to only have for dashes(hyphens) in the title section, even if it has a parenthesis it would remove it and just add dashes, possible?

Comment: Hmm possible but challenging and may I suggest that should be a separate question since nature of the problem is very different. When you create a new question just leave the link in comment here and I will sure attend it.

Comment: I must have accidentally clicked on it for some reason, it work's perfectly, I have no reason to unaccepted, but fixed.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20087549/hide-php-extension-force-trailing-slash

Comment: Thanks I am looking into your question and will ask my doubts about it on the other question.